# (Hack to get Auth to work) ERROR: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name (clickhouse sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

**Issue:** When using **Sqlalchemy**(Python/Pandas Dataframe) to connect to **Clickhouse** DB, below error occurs when attempting to **authenticate** credentials.

**Error:** `default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name (version 21.8.10.19 (official build))`

**Environment/Version details:**

> Python - 3.7.xx

> infi.clickhouse-orm - 2.XX.xx (Earlier version)

**Solution:** Downgrade **infi.clickhouse-orm** to **1.0.4** *(CLI: pip install infi.clickhouse-orm==1.0.4)*

**Git Reference:** https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/pull/45

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

That project is no longer actively maintained and has multiple issues when connecting with current versions of ClickHouse.

For Pandas/Numpy you should look at either the native https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver or the new ClickHouse Inc. supported clickhouse-connect project https://pypi.org/project/clickhouse-connect